# LINQ and data visualization

Tags: linq

when we populate dataset or datatable the we can place the cursor on the instace of datatable or dataset and then a popup comes and there is a button where we click and then a window appear with data from there we can see what data is stored in dataset or datatable. so when we work with linq is there any way to see what data is stored in linq resultset please discuss in detail how to see what data is fetched and stored in linq result set when we debug. thanks

Comment: Worst question formulation of the week award

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because LINQ expressions usually result in a projection with lazy evaluation and deferred execution, in order to see the results of a LINQ expression, it needs to be executed.

There is a little green "cycle" arrow saying something like "enumerate results" in the watch window that, when clicked, will execute the expression and show the results.

Comment: can u please tell me the process in detail for data visualization. thanks.

Comment: Well, You know the return type of a linq expression but I'm not sure how you want to visualise this.

Answer (score 2):

Nevertheless: have a look at [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net). I believe it will have *exactly what you need*

Comment: without using Linq pad can i visualize from vs2010 IDE when we debug the code.